# blur image algorithm is not working properly

Tags: java, image

I have implemented the *blur* algorithm. I don't understand *why* it is producing *blue color* although the original image is *not* blue.I think problem is in here (the sum of all colors) 
                int sum = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9)/9;
Please help me. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
public class BlurImageDemo1 {

BlurImageDemo1() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File f = new File("D:\\mk.jpg");
    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(f);
    for (int x = 1; x < im.getHeight() - 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < im.getWidth() - 2; y++) {
            Color p1 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x-1));
            int s1=p1.getRed()+p1.getGreen()+p1.getBlue() ;

            Color p2 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x - 1));
            int s2=p2.getRed()+p2.getGreen()+p2.getBlue() ;

            Color p3 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x - 1));
            int s3=p3.getRed()+p3.getGreen()+p3.getBlue() ;

            Color p4 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x));
            int s4=p4.getRed()+p4.getGreen()+p4.getBlue() ;

            Color p5 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x));
            int s5=p5.getRed()+p5.getGreen()+p5.getBlue();

            Color p6 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x));
            int s6=p6.getRed()+p6.getGreen()+p6.getBlue() ;

            Color p7 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x + 1));
            int s7=p7.getRed()+p7.getGreen()+p7.getBlue() ;

            Color p8 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x + 1));
            int s8=p8.getRed()+p8.getGreen()+p8.getBlue() ;

            Color p9 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x + 1));
            int s9=p9.getRed()+p9.getGreen()+p9.getBlue() ;

            int sum = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9)/9;
            System.out.println(sum);
            im.setRGB(y, x,sum);


        }
        //System.out.println();
    }
    ImageIO.write(im, "jpg", new File("D:\\MK1.jpg"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    new BlurImageDemo1();
}
}
```

[image: This is the original image.]

[image: This is converted image.It should be blurred, I don't know why it is blue.]

Comment: Why are you summing the channels?

Comment: i dont get it. did u see the original image. there is no blue color. how is it posible. please explain

Comment: Well I find this question a bit mysterious because it looks intentional. You sum up red green and blue resulting in a badly-mixed luminance, you blur that, and then you pretend that the luminance is RGB which it isn't, but of course the majority of it is in the lowest 8 bits - so blue.

Comment: i am just learning image processing.i dont have good understanding of color mix up. and i am not pretending anything. if you can help me .it would be great.

Comment: can u please correct the code for me.

Comment: Ok sure, it'll take a minute or so

Comment: thank you. i have been trying it for almost 5h. thn i got the idea of sharing the code online.

Comment: @harold can you please upvote my question.

Comment: Thank you @harold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color channels should not be mixed here, so it takes 3 separate blurs.

```
// get the pixels
Color p1 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x-1));
Color p2 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x - 1));
Color p3 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x - 1));
Color p4 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x));
Color p5 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x));
Color p6 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x));
Color p7 = new Color(im.getRGB(y - 1, x + 1));
Color p8 = new Color(im.getRGB(y, x + 1));
Color p9 = new Color(im.getRGB(y + 1, x + 1));
// blur all components separately
int r = (p1.getRed() + p2.getRed() + p3.getRed() + 
         p4.getRed() + p5.getRed() + p6.getRed() + 
         p7.getRed() + p8.getRed() + p9.getRed()) / 9;
int g = (p1.getGreen() + p2.getGreen() + p3.getGreen() + 
         p4.getGreen() + p5.getGreen() + p6.getGreen() + 
         p7.getGreen() + p8.getGreen() + p9.getGreen()) / 9;
int b = (p1.getBlue() + p2.getBlue() + p3.getBlue() + 
         p4.getBlue() + p5.getBlue() + p6.getBlue() + 
         p7.getBlue() + p8.getBlue() + p9.getBlue()) / 9;
// write back result
blurredim.setRGB(y, x, b + (g << 8) + (r << 16));
```

Note that it is important to store the pixels in a *new* image, otherwise the written pixel affects the results of the pixels to the right and bottom of it.

There are also better blurs and it would be faster not to use `Color` and instead just deconstruct the colors manually with bitmath, but I felt this was outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: What if you use the int from `getRGB()`?

Comment: OMG. "you are great". you did it in just a min.. i did it just to understand how bluring works. and thanks again for the help..

Comment: @matt then it would be faster but it would likely confuse OP more because of all the bitmath, so I just kept it a suggestion

Comment: I am pretty sure you could just use the value returned by getRGB, average that, and then use setRGB, without ever dealing with the components individually.

Comment: @matt no you can't, the components would mix in odd ways. For example, 0xFFFFFF plus 8 black pixels divided by 9 is 0x1c71c7, a weird bluish colour.

Comment: Okay true, because the remainder due to dividing the higher bits you need to mask, or do the components like you say.